# Changing a pandas dataframe column based on a specific condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Say I have a dataframe of weight and price.

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'weight': [1,2,0,3,4,5,0], 'price': [10,20,30,40,50,60,70]})
```

**Question:** How can I change the price column value if I spot a weight of 0? (In this case I want to set the price to 0.96 if wieght = 0 with everything else left the same). Would appreciate multiple methods along with an explanation of which to use in which scenario if possible.

**Tried:**

```
if df1['weight'] == 0:
  df1['price'] = 0.96
```

However when this is tried an error comes up with an error `ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().` I know I must be doing something trivally wrong but if someone could explain this and provide the best possible solutions that would be great.

**Desired Output**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'weight': [1,2,0,3,4,5,0], 'price': [10,20,0.96,40,50,60,0.96]})
```

Same dataframe but with the prices changed.

Comment: Use `df1.loc[df1['weight'] == 0, 'price'] = 0.96`

Comment: or ```df1['price'] = np.where(df1['weight'] == 0,0.96, df1['price'])```

Comment: Great thanks. Would you be able to explain why what I tried didn't work? Is there something floored about trying to use an `if statement` like this?